# Rails4, CKEditor gem, precompiled assets : Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource Name "Default" was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to put in production mode a website. For a reason, I had to use precompiled assets, which I did with :

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

(The reason is I use mod_passenger and I couldn't get anything working without precompiled assets).

All worked fine, but not the CKEditor. I use the galetahub / ckeditor gem. It was working fine in development thought, but in production I have the following error :

```
 Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource Name "Default" was not found at "[...]/assets/ckeditor/styles.js?t=D6IE
```

and in the place of the editor I have... nothing.

I've already tried some solution found there and there, like adding :

```
//= require ckeditor/override
```

But with this I can't precompile the assets, it give me an "ckeditor/override not found" error.

I've also tried to define the CKEDITOR_BASEPATH, which changed.. nothing.

The path to the .js seems good, except that in the ckeditor repository I have nothing named styles.js, but I guess the assets pipeline redirect it ?

Thanks for your help, I'm out of idea.

Comment: Did you end up finding the problem?

Comment: I'm still getting this issue on the hosted version of the library.